# Apollo server 4 , custom directive migration

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

So i have some custome directives built into a custom package using `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` from the package ```apollo-server-express``

```
class AuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {....
```

and then i add them into the schema using `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` from package `graphql-tools` ,(the function is now removed from the package since version 6)

```
const directives = { upper: UpperDirective, isAuth: AuthDirective };
SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitSchemaDirectives(schema, directives);
```

but now that i want to upgrade to apollo v4 i can't find this function no where and can't figure out the new way of doing it which semes to require creating a tranformer function that takes care of that https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/schema-directives